# How do I create a tcp socket in promiscuous mode?

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, packet-sniffers

I am trying to write an application that will read data mirrored from another tcp/ip connection.

Device A connects to machine B via tcp/ip and sends it data. The sent data is duplicated and sent to machine C from device A, but with the same destination address as it did before (pointing to B not C). machine C needs to read the data and do stuff with it.

My question is how do I create a socket that will do this? I know I will need to have it in promiscuous mode. Does it need to be a RAW socket? What is the best way to get the data?

machine C will basically be a network sniffer I guess, but on a network only consisting of those 3 devices.

Comment: Why not use an actual sniffing library, like pcap? Let it deal with the details of capturing the packets.

Comment: Because I'm a noob, and I didn't know what that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use libpcap to grab raw packets.  Run `man 3 pcap` to get a list of all the relevant functions.